# How to pick first or random row from multiple rows returned in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

**Code:**

```
select product.code, product.description, salesorder.number, customer.name, 'Quantity' as Quantity, barcode.barcode
from salesorderline 
join salesorder on salesorderline.salesorderid = salesorder.id
join product on salesorderline.productid = product.id
join barcode on product.id = barcode.productid
join customer on salesorder.customerid = customer.id
```

**Output:**

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YEbFS.jpg)

**Problem:**

More than one codes are returned, because there is multiple barcodes attached to it.

Within the database, more than 1 barcode is attached to the codes.

How can I return just 1 random value of barcode instead of all? that are attached to the code.

**SQL DATABASE:**

Database Is stored in Microsoft SQL

**What I have tried:**

```
select product.code, product.description, salesorder.number, customer.name, 'Quantity' as Quantity, barcode.barcode
from salesorderline 
join salesorder on salesorderline.salesorderid = salesorder.id
join product on salesorderline.productid = product.id
join barcode on product.id = barcode.productid
join customer on salesorder.customerid = customer.id
group by barcode.barcode
```

but the error is:

```
Error: Column 'product.code' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
```

Comment: `ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1` if this is for MySQL

Comment: What dbms are you using? Because there is different syntax for different dbms.

Comment: @ErgiNushi just using SQL not MySQL

Comment: You cannot just use SQL. But based on your edit, it is MS SQL Server.

Comment: @ErgiNushi that's correct :)

Comment: @Bartender_ when asking for "sql" it's always better to include the type of dbms you are using in order to get the required response.

Comment: @ErgiNushi ill keep that in mind. Thanks for the tip

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server

```
SELECT TOP 1 MyColumn FROM MyTable
ORDER BY NEWID()
```

There's no RAND in SQL server as far as i know
but you can use `NEWID()` which create  a unique value which is basiclly the same as RAND()

More Info about NEWID() can be foudn at [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/newid-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: how would the query differ if I have multiple columns to select? And using `join`

Comment: sql-server `rand()` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/rand-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend `cross apply`:

```
select p.code, p.description, so.number, c.name,
       'Quantity' as Quantity, bc.barcode
from salesorderline sol join
     salesorder so
     on sol.salesorderid = so.id join
     product p
     on sol.productid = p.id join
     customer c
     on so.customerid = c.id cross apply
     (select top (1) bc.*
      from barcode bc
      where p.id = bc.productid
      order by newid()
     ) bc;
```

Technically, `apply` implements *lateral joins*.  These are a very powerful type of join.  In this case, the `join` is equivalent to a correlated subquery, but a correlated subquery that returns multiple columns.

Comment: Hi, this is working fine! Tested it. Do you mind if you explain what's actually happening? I'll accept the answer in that case.

Comment: @Bartender_ . . . I thought I had explained it.